# Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid operation

Tags: sharepoint-online, win-form

I am using the following code in a Winforms app to upload an image file to SharePoint Online:

```
    Try
        Using ctx As ClientContext = ClaimClientContext.GetAuthenticatedContext(url, 0, 0)
            If Not ctx Is Nothing Then
                Dim Web As Web = ctx.Web
                Dim newFile As FileCreationInformation

                ctx.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
                newFile = New FileCreationInformation()
                newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("a.tif")
                newFile.Url = "a.tif"
                Dim docs1 As List = Web.Lists.GetByTitle("My Images")
                Dim uploadFile As File = docs1.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile)

                ctx.ExecuteQuery()

                txtMessage.Text = "File uploaded"
            End If
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
```

It throws the following error on `ExecuteQuery`:

**Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid operation. Use Form.ShowDialog instead.**

Works fine in a Console app, but was unable to find an example using Windows Forms.

Also works using `ClientContext`, but then I need to use the userid and password and that is not a viable solution.

Anyone know a workaround to this issue"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution.  Had to change `Application.Run(DisplayLoginForm)` to `DisplayLoginForm.ShowDialog(ClaimsWebAuth)` in ClaimsWebAuth.cs.

Comment: I am having the same problem. but when I made that change got a message "'ClaimsWebAuth' is a type, which is not valid in the given context"

Comment: @Ravi Khambhati Try `DisplayLoginForm.ShowDialog()`

Comment: this worked. Thanks